# My Drupal contact form menu item is not showing up

Tags: drupal, drupal-contact-form

I enable the contact form module and it isn't showing up unless I'm logged into the system.  I want all users to be able to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to allow anonymous (and for good measure, authenticated) users permission to see it, via the Drupal permissions admin page.

Comment: yup - just figured that out as I was coming back in here to add a comment. :-)